# Problems with Celery & Redis Backend

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have a system set up currently that is using celery with a redis 
backend to do a bunch of asynchronous tasks such as sending emails, 
pulling social data, crawling,etc. Everything is working great, but I 
am having group figuring out how to monitor the system (aka the number 
of queue up messages). I started looking through the celery source but 
I figured I would post my questions in here: 
First off, here are my configurations:

```
BROKER_BACKEND                  = "redis" 
BROKER_HOST                     = "localhost" 
BROKER_PORT                     = 6379 
BROKER_VHOST                    = "1" 
REDIS_CONNECT_RETRY     = True 
REDIS_HOST                              = "localhost" 
REDIS_PORT                              = 6379 
REDIS_DB                                = "0" 
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS                      = True 
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL               = 'INFO' 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND           = "redis" 
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES      = 25 
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY             = 8 
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 10 
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER                     =True
```

---

The first thing I am trying to do is monitor how many messages are in 
my queue. I assume, behind the scenes, the redis backend is just 
pushing/popping from a list, although I cannot seem to find that in 
the code. So I mock up a simulation where I start about 100 tasks and 
am trying to find them in redis: 
My celeryd is running like this: 
python manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=DEBUG -n XXXXX --logfile=logs/ 
celery.log 
So I should only have 4 concurrent workers at once ..... 
Two thing I do not understand: 
Problem 1: 
After I have queued up 100 task, and look for them on redis, I only 
see the following:

```
$ redis-cli 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys * 
1) "_kombu.binding.celery" 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> select 1 
OK 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys * 
1) "_kombu.binding.celery" 
2) "_kombu.binding.celeryd.pidbox" 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]>
```

I cannot seem to find the tasks to get a number of how many are queued 
(technically, 96 should be since I only support 4 concurrent tasks)

Problem 2

```
$ ps aux | grep celeryd | cut -c 13-120 
 41258   0.2  0.2  2526232   9440 s004  S+    2:27PM   0:07.35 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=DEBU 
 41261   0.0  0.1  2458320   2468 s004  S+    2:27PM   0:00.09 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=DEBU 
 38457   0.0  0.8  2559848  34672 s004  T    12:34PM   0:18.59 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=INFO 
 38449   0.0  0.9  2517244  36752 s004  T    12:34PM   0:35.72 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=INFO 
 38443   0.0  0.2  2524136   6456 s004  T    12:34PM   0:10.15 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=INFO 
 84542   0.0  0.0  2460112      4 s000  T    27Jan12   0:00.74 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=INFO 
 84536   0.0  0.0  2506728      4 s000  T    27Jan12   0:00.51 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=INFO 
 41485   0.0  0.0  2435120    564 s000  S+    2:54PM   0:00.00 grep 
celeryd 
 41264   0.0  0.1  2458320   2480 s004  S+    2:27PM   0:00.09 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=DEBU 
 41263   0.0  0.1  2458320   2480 s004  S+    2:27PM   0:00.09 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=DEBU 
 41262   0.0  0.1  2458320   2480 s004  S+    2:27PM   0:00.09 python 
manage.py celeryd -c 4 --loglevel=DEBU
```

If anyone could explain this for me, it would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your configuration has `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`. This means that the tasks run locally and hence you won't see them in Redis. From the docs: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager

> CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER
>
> If this is True, all tasks will be executed
>   locally by blocking until the task returns. apply_async() and
>   Task.delay() will return an EagerResult instance, which emulates the
>   API and behavior of AsyncResult, except the result is already
>   evaluated.
>
> That is, tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the
>   queue.

Answer (score 1):

Never used Celery but if you want to figure what it is doing one of the ways to go about it is to connect to the Redis instance using redis-cli then run `monitor` command. This will dump all commands being executed against the Redis database. You will be able to see exactly what is going on.